# Area bounded by $\frac{x}{e^x+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

I would like to find an area bounded by curves $x=a, x=2a, y=0$ and $y=\frac{x}{e^x+1}$ where $a>0$.

**What I tried:**
So basically I need to find $\int_{a}^{2a}\frac{x}{e^x+1}dx$.
As [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%2F%28e%5Ex%2B1%29&lang=ja) suggests, the antiderivative cannot be expressed by the elementary functions. However, this question is supposed to be a high-school level (in my country) question so I believe the answer must be represented by the elementary functions. However, I am not sure how to calculate it without using any special functions.

Comment: As stated, I agree it is not elementary, I would go for a typo, with $e^{x+1}$ it is easily calculable.

Comment: @zwim This seems to be the most reasonable option.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or a picture of the original source of this assignment? I agree with the above comments, there's probably some mistake

Comment: @YuriyS Unfortunately no, but I am going to ask the person who gave me this question if this is the correct question.

Comment: It could also be $e^x/(e^x+1)$, seems much more likely. For that matter $e^x/(e^x-1)$ would make for a more interesting answer with $2a$ and $a$ being the limits